# get the sum of datas in the same date and get an array for weekly reports

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
Orders
+--------+-------------------------------------------+--------+
|  id    |    date_stamp                             | amount |
+--------+-------------------------------------------+--------+
|   1    |      November 10, 2019 12:46:03 AM        |  10    |
|   2    |      November 10, 2019 12:46:03 AM        |  15    |
|   3    |      November 07, 2019 12:46:03 AM        |  10    |
|   4    |      November 07, 2019 12:46:03 AM        |  15    |
|   5    |      November 07, 2019 12:46:03 AM        |  10    |
|   6    |      November 11, 2019 12:46:03 AM        |   5    |
|   7    |      November 11, 2019 12:46:03 AM        |   5    |
|   8    |      November 11, 2019 12:46:03 AM        |   5    |
|   9    |      November 11, 2019 12:46:03 AM        |   5    |
+--------+-------------------------------------------+--------+
```

I want to get the sum of each date AND the date in an array like so

November 11, 2019 = 20

November 07, 2019 = 35

November 10, 2019 = 25

I'm not sure about this syntax but I need to sets of arrays the DATE(distinct) and the sum for each date

I need two sets of array because I'm going to use it in a bar graph

I tried this statement but I cant make it work, must be wrong.

```
 $statement="SELECT SUM(amount), date_stamp from orders"
```

I'm trying to get the dates and amounts starting today to 6 days prior to make a sales report for the week

Answer (score 2):

use aggregation and convert date time to date by using `DATE_FORMAT` function

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date_stamp, '%M %D %Y')
as date_stamp,sum(amount) as amount from table_name
where date(date_stamp)>= date(now()) and date(date_stamp)<= date(now()-6)
group by DATE_FORMAT(date_stamp, '%M %D %Y')
```

Comment: It works, but I want to only get the dates that ranges today and 6days before (making it a week) so the maximum data I will have is 7

Comment: @Remaster ok just need where condtion i going to put that please accept if it helps

Comment: it returned an error "Unknown column 'now' in 'where clause'"

Comment: @Remaster check now there was a typo i missed ()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202207/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-re-master).